# I cannot access req.body. console.log doesn't print the request object;

Tags: node.js, express, req

```
const { render } = require("ejs");

const express= require("express");

const app = express();

const path = require('path');


app.use(express.static('views'));

app.set('view engine','ejs');

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname,'/views','ejs'));

app.get('/',(req,res)=>

{

 res.render('homepage2.ejs')

})

app.get('/gallery',(req,res)=>

{
    res.render('gallery.ejs')

})

**app.get('/termin',(req,res)=>

{
    console.log(req.body);

    res.render('termin2.ejs', {currentMonth:"Януари"});

})**

app.listen('3000',()=>

{

    console.log('listening on port 3000');

})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `GET`, if you want to send your data in body, you should change from `GET` to `POST` so

```
app.post('/termin',(req,res) => {
      console.log(req.body);
})
```